# Does ApiInformation not respect the app target version

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Imagine the following setup:

**UWP Library:**
MinVersion: 10240
TargetVersion: 16299

This library checks at runtime if the UniversalApiContract Version 5 is present.
If yes, it will use the new NavigationView control that.

**UWP App:**
MinVersion: 10240
TargetVersion: 10240

This app references the UWP Library project.
When I run this app on my Computer, which has Windows 10 Version 16299 installed, the following happens:
The UWP Library checks at runtime for the api contract. As I have the newest version of Windows 10, yes it is present.
Then it tries to create the NavigationView control, and I get a TypeLoadException with the message *Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView'.*

What? Why? Does the ApiInformation class not respect the target version of the running app?

What can I do to work around this issue?
I thought ApiInformation was the way to avoid this, but apparently not?!

Here is a Github repository showcasing the error:
https://github.com/haefele/ApiInformationTargetVersionFail

If you set the target-version of the MyApp project to 16299, everything works fine.

Comment: Your app is targetting 10240 so it and all its dependencies could only use APIs available in 10240.

Comment: Thats exactly why I'm trying to use the ApiInformation class to check if the API is available in the app. But the ApiInformation class says "yep, its available", but when I try to use it I get the TypeLoadException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Edit May 29 2018]*

The methods of [the `ApiInformation` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) are based on a trivial lookup of the WinRT metadata on disk -- if the metadata is there, the call succeeds. This enables "light-up" of new features on new platforms without increasing your minimum version. What's important though is that `ApiInformation` knows nothing about the *implementation* of the API: sometimes it might be missing (eg on early "Insider" builds of the OS) and sometimes it might not work due to "quirks" (see example below). .NET also had a different view of the world due to the way the JIT and .NET Native toolchains work.

This can cause problems...

.NET apps use a concept of a "Union WinMD" which is the union of all known types (including Extension SDKs) that exist in the Windows SDK that corresponds to the `MaxVersionTested` setting of the app. If you're running the app on a down-level platform, `ApiInformation` will tell you the API doesn't exist, but .NET can still JIT methods based on the Union WinMD and perform some reflection tasks. If you actually try and call the API (because you forgot the `ApiInformation` check) you will get a `MissingMethodException` at runtime because the API doesn't really exist.

A different problem can occur if you include a higher-versioned .NET library inside a lower-versioned app and then try to run it on the higher-versioned build of the OS. In this case, `ApiInformation` will succeed because the type exists in the system metadata, but .NET will throw a `MissingMethodException` at runtime because *the type didn't exist in the Union WinMD used to build the app*.

**Important:** This is based on the Target Version (aka `MaxVersionTested`) of *the app*, not the library!

If you build a release version of the app, you will even see the .NET Native toolchain display a warning such as this in the Output window:

> `warning : ILTransform : warning ILT0003: Method 'Foo.Bar()' will always throw an exception due to the missing method 'SomeNewType.NewMethod()'. There may have been a missing assembly.`

There is no good way around this, other than to build your application with the same target version as the library (so that it can resolve all the references).

Another problem you can encounter is when your app (or a library it consumes) use APIs "from the future" that didn't exist in the OS listed as the `MaxVersionTested` of the app. Many of the APIs will work, but some don't due to incompatibilities with the simulated legacy mode the app is running in.

#### Hypothetical example of the library problem

Imagine that version X of the OS only supported black-and-white apps, where the background is always white and text, graphics, etc. are always black. Apps are built using this underlying assumption - including having graphics buffers that allocate only 1-bit-per-pixel, or never worrying about text being invisible because the background and foreground colours are the same. Everything is fine.

Now version Y of the OS comes out, and it supports colour graphics (say, 8-bits-per-pixel). Along with this new feature comes a pair of new APIs, `SetForegroundColor()` and `SetBackgroundColor()` that let you choose whatever colour you want. Any app (or library) that asks `ApiInformation` whether these two new APIs exists *will succeed* on version Y of the OS, and any app with a `MaxVersionTested` of at least Y can use them successfully. But for compatibility reasons *they cannot work* in an app that only targeted version X because it has no idea colours exist. Their graphics buffers are the wrong size, their text might become invisible, and so on. So the APIs will fail at runtime when used in an X-targeted app, even though the OS has the metadata (and the implementation) to support them.

Unfortunately there is no good way of handling this situation today, but it is a relatively rare occurrence. It is equivalent to a legacy Win32 library using `LoadLibrary` / `GetProcAddress` (or a legacy .NET library using reflection) to discover APIs that are "from the future."

Comment: But this sounds as if the issue should only appear when I'm running the app with a debugger, right? Because even if I create a app-package and install the app on my machine, I still get the same issue.

Comment: The last paragraph is what you're likely hitting. The type exists but can't be created in the context of an older app (due to compatibility settings).

Comment: But how do I work around this issue then? Imagine I have an app that uses the UWP Community Toolkit. I update the nuget package of the toolkit, and still be on creators update myself. Now whoever runs the app on fall creators update will get an error? (The documentation to MaxVersionTestes says that its equal to TargetVersion if its set to 10.0.0.0, which it is in my case)

Comment: I'm talking about the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-targetdevicefamily It states that if you only target Windows.Universal with MinVersion 10.0.0.0 and MaxVersionTested 10.0.0.0, the values from the csproject target-min-Version and target-version are used instead.

Comment: Hmm, thats not cool. Do you know where I could file an issue for this? Because to me it feels like a ticking time-bomb for everyone using third-party libraries in his UWP app.

Comment: Yes, if I up the target-version of the app to 16299 (fall creators update), then everything works correctly.

Comment: I beefed up the answer a bit with more info. We're aware of the problem, but if you want to voice your opinion you can use http://wpdev.uservoice.com