# Windows Runtime Component and ApiInformation.IsTypePresent

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-runtime

I have a C# Windows Runtime Component project. It has a minimum windows version X, and targets windows version Z.

Internally, it uses `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(NewType)` to detect a new type that appears in windows version Z and uses it if available.

Now I have a C# Universal Windows app that consumes the previous project. If I set the app project to minimum windows X, and target windows Z, everything works as expected.

However if I set the app project to minimum version X, and target version Y (which doesn't contain the new type):

- The app compiles.
- Running on a windows version Z machine, `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent(NewType)` returns `true` which is good.

However when I actually try to use that new type, under Debug (with .NET Native unchecked) I get an exception with:

> Could not find Windows Runtime type 'NewType'.

Under Release (with .NET Native checked), the type is apparently found, but I get an exception when calling a method on it:

> Method 'NewType.Method()' was not included in compilation, but was referenced in '...' There may have been a missing assembly.

Is there something I need to do to the component project so that app consumers don't have to target windows Z? The whole point of the project is that it's a compatibility layer that app consumers can consume. that will, if the new type is present, use it, otherwise use older types instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does ApiInformation not respect the app target version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47540577/does-apiinformation-not-respect-the-app-target-version)